# CSS flexbox vertically/horizontally center image WITHOUT explicitely defining parent height

Tags: css, flexbox

With **only** the parent `div` and the child `img` elements as demonstrated below how do I vertically *and* horizontally center the `img` element while **explicitly not** defining the `height` of the parent `div`?

```
<div class="do_not_define_height">
 <img alt="No, he'll be an engineer." src="theknack.png" />
</div>
```

I'm not too familiar with flexbox so I'm okay if flexbox itself fills up the full height, but not any other unrelated properties.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Without explicitly defining the `height` I determined I need to apply the `flex` value to the parent *and* grandparent `div` elements...

```
<div style="display: flex;">
<div style="display: flex;">
 <img alt="No, he'll be an engineer." src="theknack.png" style="margin: auto;" />
</div>
</div>
```

---

If you're using a single element (e.g. dead-centered text in a single `flex` element) use the following:

```
align-items: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: Interested in centering an image both vertically and horizontally w/out explicitly setting a height on its parents. I have a series of image and want the height of the tallest image to be the height of the parent and center all other sibling images.

It looks like you might have something here, do you have a demo?

Comment: Hi Steve, I'll post something on my site (see profile) tonight for you, just keep in mind I'll be home late.

Comment: Hey John, no worries, whenever you can post it, I appreciate it buddy! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Steve Better late than never? https://www.jabcreations.com/blog/dead-center-dynamic-overflow-height-dialog-box-with-flexbox Also there are some issues with older browsers (e.g. Safari 5 and IE) where they go by the older model.

Answer (score 136):

Just add the following rules to the parent element:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
align-items: center; /* align vertical */
```

Here's a **[sample demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/vc4cd02a/)** (Resize window to see the image align)

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for Flexbox nowadays is quite good.

For cross-browser compatibility for `display: flex` and `align-items`, you can add the older flexbox syntax as well:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: That defines `height`, I explicitly stated I can *not* define `height` except for flexbox.

Comment: @John - no it doesn't define a height - the height in the fiddle is only there for testing .... when you resize the window you can see the height of the container **changing** and the img is still centered. You can remove the height rule and it will work for whatever the height of the container is.

Comment: @John - No! In your forked fiddle the height of the parent div is the height of the image!!! so obviously it won't align. In order to center the image it must be within a container with a greater width and height than the image.

Comment: Yeah, I know that part; I'm stumped on how to make `height: 100%` actually be what it looks like it should be. :-\

Comment: @John here is an updated version of your forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Ld8bcc0p/1/ - just add `width:100%` and `height:100%` on the inner div

Comment: The problem is that we're still **explicitly** defining the parent element using view port units. That is why I figured flexbox would *flex*; I'm pretty sure I saw that watching the IE blog at some point...

Comment: @John No! the height of the container could be anything just as long as it is greater than the image. Plug in any value you want for height and flexbox will center it.

Comment: Scroll a page or so to the vertical version: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/#flex-pack ... I think this is what we're missing though I've already implemented that code and I *still* think I'm missing something...

Comment: I figured it out and posted an answer. I hate spending time helping people to get snubbed off so I'm giving you +1 for your time. Thank you!

Comment: Aaaaaaand it doesnt work