# How to center a child div vertically in a parent div that contains a scroll bar?

Tags: html, css

I know how to vertically center a div on a web page alone by using position: absolute; but how can I make the child div call internal-container vertically center in the parent div call message-box that contains a scrollbar the red cuts off AKA the internal-container how can I resolve this?

```css
body{
  color: white;
}

#message-box{
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: black;
overflow: auto;
}

#internal-container{
  background-color: red;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  word-break: break-all;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='message-box'>
  <div id='internal-container'>
    <p>
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
    </p>
  </div><!--</internal-container>-->
</div><!--</message-box>-->
```

Comment: Look up CSS dead-center for CSS 2 compatibility though you may also be interested in *my* answer to my own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832340/css-flexbox-vertically-horizontally-center-image-without-explicitely-defining-pa

Comment: Also go to the link in my profile and at the top-right of the site click on stuff like 'Site Themes' and look at the CSS code used in the Developer Tools Inspector tab.

Comment: and what is centring for you in such case?

Answer (score 0):

Make parent `div` `display: flex` and `justify-content: center;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300vh;
  background: #338cb0;
  display: flex;  
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.child {
  width: 80%;
  height: 120px;
  background: #770022;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```