# why do some of my pictures change positioning?

Tags: html, css

I have a few pictures on my website and I have been using `position: relative` for all of them. I am just wondering why, if I altered one picture of delete it, it will somehow affect the rest of the pictures? Also, when should I use relative, absolute and static? Can I use static for all of them if they are in a fixed position? I read that the parent's class should be a position relative while the child's should be position absolute, is that correct?

Comment: using `position` can be troublesome, some browsers render it different.  Mainly sub IE9 ones, but I remember the days of IE6.

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS

Comment: `if I altered one picture of delete it, it will somehow affect the rest of the pictures` this is probably because you don't have a well defined  "row" and "cell" type structure.  In other words everything is relative to the largest image (typically height).  It's not necessarily a bad thing though.  Depends how liquid you need the page to be.  Image positioning can be a pain, using `flex`  (in modern browsers) can be a better way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832340/css-flexbox-vertically-horizontally-center-image-without-explicitely-defining-pa

Comment: It would really help if you can post your code

Comment: should i post all of my CSS?

Comment: I am still curious though.. can I use position static for all of my pictures and will this solve the problem?

Comment: would position static solve my problem here or would you still need to see my whole css code?