# What's a simple CSS method to complete my "cross?"

Tags: html, css

[image]I want to create a special box/div for this message board which adds the top part of the cross to this project. Ideally, this solution will allow a small picture to the left of the bar and the banner/logo will occupy the space to the right of the top bar.

I cannot wrap my head around how to create two div elements where the left side is a fixed width and the right side fills the remaining browser space. link to test-site: https://bchristiancross.runboard.com

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #FF0000;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  height: 175px;
  background: #FFFF80;
}

#content,
#footer {
  margin-left: 175px;
  border: 1px solid #0000FF;
  border-left: 50px solid #0000FF;
}

#content:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  left: 0;
  top: 125px;
  border-top: 50px solid #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="header">
    board banner/logo goes here
    <h1>Your board name here</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- end header -->

  <div id="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its not clear what the issue is? is it the blue cross not spaning the entire width or is the question related to how to make this layout?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the effect you're trying to achieve, you could visually represent what your desired outcome is?

Comment: I have added a picture showing what I am talking about when I say "completing the cross."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'css flex', I hope it helps your question.
There is good web site to learn about [CSS Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832340/css-flexbox-vertically-horizontally-center-image-without-explicitely-defining-pa)

Following code is an example that you might want to do, I hope it answers your question.

index.html

```
<div id="header" class="flex_container">
  <div class="flex_left">
    <img alt="picture" src="">
  </div>
  <div class="flex_right">
    board banner/logo goes here
    <h1>Your board name here</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

main.css

```
.flex_container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex_left{
  min-width: 175px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-right: 50px solid #0000FF;
}

.flex_right{
  width: 100%;
}
```